# confusion on constant pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
int p=10;           
const int * ptr=&p;        // expression 1
```

As far as i understood by expression 1 that the data  which is pointed by pointer ptr is constant

so if i write

```
*ptr=10;
```

which is invalid ,
 but if  i take another pointer variable like

```
int * pr=&p;
*pr=19;
cout<<*ptr;
```

will give me the ouput 19
  so now  the data pointed by ptr changed
 but earlier we have seen that data pointed by ptr is constant
   why data is changed by another pointer variable?

Comment: you will have to understand first what is constant pointer and pointer to a constant

Comment: The const qualifier is an attribute of the pointer, not of the thing being pointed to.

Comment: `const int *` means that the data can't (shouldn't) be changed through this pointer. The data itself may or may not be constant.

Comment: Expression 1 means that data can not be modified using this pointer. It does not tell that data which is pointed by pointer is constant.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you for clearing my wrong concept

Answer (score 2):

`const int * ptr=&p;` means the data pointed to by `ptr` is `const`, but only relative to that pointer.

The pointed-to data is not necessarily *really* `const`  (=originally declared `const`)  and if it isn't, non-`const` pointers to it (including the original const-pointer cast to its non-const version)  may change it.

If some data is really `const`, attempts to modify it through an non-`const` pointer result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is very basic, so my suggestion is to read a basic C++ book.
Despite of that I'll provide the answer.

`int p = 10;`

It is a statement which declares and defines a variable named `p` of type `int`.
The content of this variable *can* be modified. That's because the variable `p` is *not* const.

Obviously the later statement `p = 13;` is still valid and it assigns a new value to that variable.

Now you have this:

```
const int* ptr = &p;
```

You're defining a pointer, named `ptr` which points to that variable.
Adding the qualifier `const` to the pointer it simply means that you *cannot* modify the content of the variable by means of the access of the pointer itself.

In other words, the pointer can be only used (for example) for reading the value of `p`.

On the other hand:

```
int* pr = &p;
```

defines a pointer which is not more `const` qualified.

Indeed, you can access and modify the content of the variable `p` by means of the usage of that pointer itself. (`*pr = 19;` is a valid statement).

---

**A little bit far...**

This is the general idea behind behind a "more complex world".

The statement:

```
const int* ptr = &p;
```

it's possible because the a variable can be implicitly converted in its `const` version.

Comment: thanks man for clearing my wrong concept